# How to order by sum in each rollup data group?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have my animal table with points for each animal, its color and name.

```
create table animals (
    category text,
    color text,
    name text,
    points numeric
)

insert into animals values ('CATS', 'WHITE', 'FLUFFY', 1234)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'WHITE', 'FLUFFY', 2568)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'WHITE', 'SALLY', 124)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'WHITE', 'SALLY', 12401)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'WHITE', 'MR KITTY', 101)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'WHITE', 'MR KITTY', 1761)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'BLACK', 'DARTH CATHER', 1761)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'BLACK', 'DARTH CATHER', 2361)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'BLACK', 'ITS A TRAP', 171)
insert into animals values ('CATS', 'BLACK', 'HAN SOLO', 1713)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BROWN', 'PLUTO', 1761)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BROWN', 'DUFFY', 23611)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BROWN', 'PICACHOU', 1171)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BROWN', 'DUFFY', 17123)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BLACK', 'MICKEY', 17361)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BLACK', 'JACKSON', 23361)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BLACK', 'BA', 1751)
insert into animals values ('DOGS', 'BLACK', 'MACGUYVER', 17513)
insert into animals values ('FISH', 'YELLOW', 'LENON', 1571)
insert into animals values ('FISH', 'YELLOW', 'BEUSCONI', 17153)
```

I need to return sql output similar to output from Excel pivot table:
(with proper descending order by sum of points within data groups)

[image: Pivot Table]

I'm really close with this query:

```
with data_grouped as
(
    Select
    COALESCE ( category, 'Total'::text) as category,
    COALESCE ( color, 'Total'::text) as color,
    COALESCE ( name,'Total'::text) as name,
    sum(points) as points   
    FROM animals
    GROUP BY category, color, name
),
data_evolutions as
(
select  grouping(d.category, d.color, d.name) as GR_ALL,
    d.category,
    d.color,
    d.name,
    sum(d.points) as points

from data_grouped d
group by rollup(d.category, d.color, d.name)
order by category, color, name
)
select
    COALESCE (d.category, 'Total'::text) as "CATEGORY",
    COALESCE (d.color, 'Total'::text) as "COLOR",
    COALESCE (d.name, 'Total'::text) as "NAME",
    points

from data_evolutions d
order by 
CASE WHEN category IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, category,
CASE WHEN color IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, color, 
CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, points desc
```

but still I get wrong order.

[image: current SQL output]

Animals are ordered by name, not by sum.
How should I change my query to get descending order by sum of points within each level?

I need correct sums, and order with totals and subtotals.

Comment: `order by  ... nulls first`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nulls first or last still return query with CATS higher than DOGS.- ordered alfabethically